# HttpWebRequest Image is loading with delay

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

So i am sending a httpwebrequest to a particular website and i need an image from that website but this image loads 3-5 seconds after the the request is complete so the source does not contain the image, i want to make some kind of a delay so i can get the response a few seconds later, this is my code:

```
HttpWebRequest req1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");            
            using(var httpResponse = req1.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var ResponseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (ResponseStream != null)
                    {
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ResponseStream))
                        {

                            string response = sr.ReadToEnd();                            
                            var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                            doc.Load(ResponseStream);

                            foreach(HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("src"))//it's not working because the source does not contain the image
                            {
                                pictureBox1.ImageLocation = node.ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Get the response a few seconds later than what? It sounds like it may be a client-side programmatic delay, e.g. in Javascript... but at the moment you're basically not being clear.

Comment: as i said the website loads the image a few seconds later so i need the response a few seconds later in order to capture that image, i think i am clear

Comment: No, you're really not. You need to think about what's *really* happening here. Josh's answer basically gives more detail about that. It's not a matter of asking the server for the response a few seconds later - it's about what the browser *does* with the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is likely happening is that the page is loaded then a Javascript event fires and makes a separate call to the server to load the image. Delaying your HTTP request will not help you achieve what you desire.

I would suggest

1. opening the page in Google Chrome, and pressing Ctr-Shift-J to bring up the Developer Tools.
2. Click on the network tab.
3. Click on "Images" at the botton of the Developer's tool.
4. Click on the network tab.
5. Navigate to the page with your image. You'll see a request for the image in Developer Tools.
6. Try and figure out where that request is being created within the Javascript.

If you provide a link to the page you're talking about, myself or others might be able to clarify further.

Comment: https://edit.yahoo.com/registration?.src=fpctx&.intl=us&.done=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com%2F

Comment: See also @scotthanselman's excellent post the Internet isn't a black box: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheInternetIsNotABlackBoxLookInside.aspx

Comment: i inspected it carefully but i still dont get the idea how to deal with it